# How to take average of column in specific date ranges using R?

Tags: r, statistics

I know there might be similar questions like this but i can't find any specific answers for my condition. I have a dataframe like this:

```
date          CVDadmissions
2001.10.01         48
2001.10.02         12
2002.10.01         24
2002.10.02         22
```

What I want is:

- average of cvdadmissions for 2001 and then for 2002.

Can someone please guide me how can i do in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(df$CVDadmissions,list(substr(df$date,1,4)),mean)
```

Comment: what does 1 and 4 here referring to?

Comment: @hasanarshad The function extracts a substring from date from location 1 to 4, that is the first four characters of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `Date` object, extract year and then take `mean`

```
aggregate(CVDadmissions~year, 
   transform(df, year = format(as.Date(date, "%Y.%m.%d"), "%Y")), mean)

#  year CVDadmissions
#1 2001            30
#2 2002            23
```

With `dplyr` and `lubridate`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(year = year(date)) %>%
  summarise(CVDadmissions = mean(CVDadmissions))
```

Comment: Ronak. Thank you. so what could be the code if we have done month-wise average within years for month 1-12. i will be thankful if you share that code as well.

Comment: @hasanarshad In that case, extract month and year in that case. `aggregate(CVDadmissions~year_month, 
          transform(df, year_month = format(as.Date(date, "%Y.%m.%d"), "%Y-%m")), mean)`